# Opening a file with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

The 'reader' within the if statement is showing

> Expression is not a method

```vb
Dim reader As New CSVReader

OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "CSV File (*.csv)|*.csv"
OpenFileDialog2.RestoreDirectory = True
If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    reader(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)
    reader.DisplayResults(DataGridView1)
    'Return OpenFileDialog2.FileName
Else
End If
```

I moved the Dim and it worked.

```
OpenFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "a:"
OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "CSV File (*.csv)|*.csv"
OpenFileDialog2.RestoreDirectory = True
If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim reader As New CSVReader(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)
    reader.DisplayResults(DataGridView1)
    'Return OpenFileDialog2.FileName
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
reader(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)
```

You're trying to call a constructor on an object that is already constructed. That's not possible, so the VB compiler is interpreting this as you trying to call the reader object as if it were a function.

Just don't declare the reader until you have the filename, so that you can pass the name to the constructor when you actually construct it, like so

```
    OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "CSV File (*.csv)|*.csv"
    OpenFileDialog2.RestoreDirectory = True
    If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim reader As New CSVReader(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)
        reader.DisplayResults(DataGridView1)
        'Return OpenFileDialog2.FileName
    Else
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the method name in `reader(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)`.